90's movie about a car accident survivor who has amnesia
I watched a 90's movie in the past but I forgot the title. 
The plot is about a husband who survives a car accident, but now has amnesia. He spent his time finding the truth about the rumour that his wife was trying to cheat on him. He later found his wife's boyfriend was already dead, and he found his body at a water tank. When he lifted the body, he then found that it's actually himself.
Could you help me find the title of this movie?

If the water tank is actually formaldehyde, it could be Shattered (1991).
Wikipedia has the plot summary. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shattered_(1991_film).

Dan receives a phone call from Jenny imploring him to see her, but Dan finds Jenny dead. He is confronted at gunpoint by Gus, who thinks Dan must have murdered Stanton. Pleading for his life, Dan convinces Gus to visit the shipwreck, where they find a chemical storage container. Dan dredges up a body of a man who looks exactly like himself. Dan realizes he is not Dan Merrick; he is Jack Stanton.
. . . .
Judith had banked on the chemical dissolving Dan's body, but because it was actually Formaldehyde, she had preserved it.

And the trailer is on YouTube. Chemical tank is at mark 1:00: 

.

Yes yes!! That's it Thanks alot

@webchun No problem, it was like the fourth link when I googled "movie amnesia wife cheats". The water tank both threw me off and was eventually a dead giveaway.

It's a cool one you guys should watch it ;)
